# Fan on CPU makes strange cracking noise

Tags: noise, fan

I recently bought a new video card for my pc.

It's a Nvidia Geforce GTX 560 Ti with dual fans on it.

Now the problem is that the smaller fan on the right starts making a very strange ticking noise once in a while. It usually lasts for hours, and only stops when i give the fan a little flick. Then it goes back to spinning normally, without that sound.

I have taken the videocard apart, taken the big metal casing off to confirm it is not touching that. But even with the whole case off, it still make that noise. I can confirm that it isn't touching anything (as far as i can see). Also the fan is clean, no dust.

I prefer not to have to send my card back to nVidia as that would leave me without a working PC for too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's new then get it replaced. They MAY be willing to send you a new one first before you return the old one.

It may run "forever" BUT no fan should make any significant noise when new and there is a significant chance that it indicates a problem that will shorten the life.

OR You may be able to find a trailing edge video card cheap for while you wait.

Comment: Correct. If a fan is making a ticking noise it's usually the bearing which is defective. Replace the fan :)